# 500- Internal Server Error when form is submitted twice to Jersey rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-client

The client used is a simple html form as shown below

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Weather Inputs</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The form </h1>
<form action= "rest/world/outlook" method="post">
Latitude : 
<input type ="text" name="lat">
Longitude :
<input type= "text" name="long">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The POST request is successful the first time it is made.However, it throws the 500 error when the form is refreshed and used again.Seems like the problem is with client destruction.
When the same client was implemented using a Jersey client ,I could handle it by using client.destroy() method.
Here is the Jersey client implementation

```
try{     
     Form form = new Form();         
     form.add("lat",100);
     form.add("long",50);
     Client c = Client.create();
     WebResource web = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/ML_PoC_Project/rest/world/outlook");
     ClientResponse response = web.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class,form);
     String output= response.getEntity(String.class);
     System.out.println(output);
     **c.destroy();**
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Could anyone suggest how the html form could be destroyed similarly?

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, you should see an exception in the server-side logs. Look at that to find out what's going on.

Comment: Its a  NumberFormatException exception and I was able to reproduce the error using the Jersey Client. The 'destroy' method solves it.But I dont know how an html form can be destroyed

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - it would help if you could post your code (a minimal example demonstrating the problem).

Comment: I have edited the post and added the client I was referring to.

Comment: It's unclear to me where the HTML comes into this - if you're calling the web service from code, then where is the HTML? If that's just HTML which happens to be displayed on a web site somewhere, that's irrelevant to what the Jersey client does. If you're *actually* seeing the problem when calling it with the HTML form (without Jersey being involved at all) then that sounds like it's simply a server side bug you should investigate without using Jersey...

Comment: Yes , you are right. The jersey is irrelevant. I tried both ways - using a Jersey client and a html form. However there is a problem  when using a form.If its a server side bug, why isnt it happening when using the client.

Comment: No idea. I suggest you use WireShark or something similar to spot the difference in requests. As it is, we basically don't have any information in this question that we can use to help you.